# ARCore how to release image acquired with acquireCameraImage

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to capture image from the ARCore camera, but doing this continuously is returning me an exception (`com.google.ar.core.exceptions.ResourceExhaustedException`) and the same log is available at JNI level too

```
E: cpu_image_manager.cc:102 Failed to acquire new image, due to too many images acquired but not released.
E: status.cc:155 ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED:
```

So I tried to find out how to release an image, and as pointed out by the [ARCore ref](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/frame#group__frame_1gaf8f99b9114e1e3058306584ba632ecd7) it's pretty easy with C (`Caller is responsible for later releasing the image with ArImage_release`) but in Java there is no release method for a `Frame` object. Is it because GC is intended to free the resource itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After having acquired the `Image` object with

```
final Image image = frame.acquireCameraImage()
```

You can free the memory calling:

```
image.close();
```

> Use the latest version ARCore SDK for Android 1.4, because prior to 1.3 `image.close()` [had a bug](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/352) with a reference received from `frame.acquireCameraImage()`

Ref: [Image.close() reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html#close())

Comment: Damn, why they called it `close` instead of `release`. I'm feeling stupid for not checking other names (actually I checked for free, destroy and dispose but hey, close is better .-.). Thanks anyway!